# Uploading latex files to the Editorial Manager

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, elsevier

A few days ago I have uploaded my article to the EM system. Next, I downloaded the generated PDF and everything was seen perfect. However, yesterday the Elsevier support team sent an email to me saying "There appears to be an error in the file [ 00main.tex ] that prevents the PDF from building correctly. Please Edit Submission and reload the file."

Now, is it possible to get an error message on their side in spite of getting no error message on my side? How is that possible? I ask them immediately but got no reply.

Here is the [manual](https://www.ariessys.com/wp-content/uploads/EM_PM_LaTeX_Guide.pdf) provided by Aries Systems for guiding Latex files.

And here is the order of the files on EM:

[The order of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjXNm.png)

Please let me know what I am missing about this EM system.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. If you are sure that the generated PDF looks fine (check it completely), I would just resubmit it and ask the journal office for more specific details about what is wrong. I see from the image that this is a revision, so the first submission must have worked fine, as well.

Comment: @Allure At the first submission I didn't upload Latex files, I uploaded the .pdf file and they didn't tell me anything. Now, they requested editable source files so I had to upload .tex files. And as I said, there were no problem in the generated PDF file, checked many times. I don't know what to do...

Comment: In that case, I would resubmit it and ask the journal office for more specific details about what is wrong, because the compiled PDF it looks fine.

Comment: @Allure I have started to think this: When EM builds PDF files one by one for each DOCX file, it puts a little explanation at the left-top corner of the pages and then merges all of them. At the first submission (not revision, the one I sent PDF file), there was the "manuscript" expression at the same location of my article's first page. However, at this time (the one with latex source files), this expression is gone for both the clean version and the changes-marked version. I am wondering if this is the problem:  It compiles my latex files but can't consider it as a manuscript file.

Comment: By the way, we have a [TeX.SE] sister site that handles technical questions about LaTeX. Without a minimum working example, I'm not sure this question would be "on topic" there, but you may want to check out their help center and consider whether they can help at all.

Comment: Also, you can have a different LaTeX version/distribution with respect to the one they are using. LaTeX has evolved quite a lot in the last years, so if you have a more recent distribution (or an older one sometimes, although it's more difficult) that could be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that the file simply got corrupted during upload/on their side. Another is that they have some issue with packages/build system overall, especially if you use some less-than-common setup.

In either case, **do what they have asked you to do**: reupload the file. Then, reply to the e-mail giving your perspective and requesting clarifications in case the issue persists.

Side note - it is not as much of an academia question as a LaTeX or, more generally, computers one. Can pipelines break for no apparent reason, especially when trying to build on a different machine than originally tested at? Yes, they do so *all the bloody time*.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible that error may be in their submission system. I will tell you my story, While i was submitting my latex files to one of the journals of Elsevier for pdf generation at their end, i always failed to get through their EM system. I finally contacted their Latex support system (elsarticle@river-valley.com) and they figured that the problem was on their end. Their submission system had outdated **elsarticle.cls** file (This is irony). I uploaded all the files again along with the **elsarticle.cls** (updated). This time i succeeded in generating the pdf.

Moral of the story!

Always ensure you have an updated versions of all the packages and files.

Note that order of the files is not important, unless you want the specific final pdf.